# Best practice for exposing internal data to outside world?

Tags: architecture, network-security, dmz

Our current setup for exposing internal data to the outside world is to have an Internet server in our DMZ with access to our database server that resides within our protected network.  But I've been told this is not secure as exposes potentially all databases to the outside world.  Is this true?

[image: Current way]

They say we should instead but an additional layer between the two.. an application server that exposes methods via, e.g. Web API, to the Internet site.  This way, only web methods are potentially exposed and not the entire database server.

Is this more "proper/ideal/best practice" architecture?  I want things as SIMPLE as possible but then also need to keep our data SECURE.  If we want to expose methods to the outside world, then an outside app would (securely of course) call the web method which would, in-turn, call the same web method on the application server.  Seems like a lot of duplication but maybe necessary in today's unsafe world?

[image: Better way?]

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Did You find a solution to your problem ?

Comment: All seems to be about mitigating as much risk as possible.  There has to be a hole of some kind somewhere, so you've just got to minimize exposure.